# Doesn't IDA Pro 6.95 support decompiling MIPS executable?

Tags: ida, decompilation, hexrays, mips

I am working on a [MIPS binary](http://www.mediafire.com/file/546xcc9bv4qcamg/bender_safe): `ELF 32-bit MSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=76438e9ed749bcfc6e191e548da153d0d3b3ee28, not stripped`
. IDA Pro 6.95 (32 bit) disassembles the file pretty well, yet the decompiler gives up: `Sorry, the current file is not decompilable`. Doesn't IDA Pro have decompilation support for MIPS?

Comment: No, it doesn't. See https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/

Comment: JEB 2.3 supports MIPS decompilation, see pnfsoftware.com/jeb2/mips (disclaimer: I am the principal author of JEB)

Comment: IDA 7.5 has MIPS decompiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, IDA version 6.95 doesn't support it. See [hex-rays.com/products/decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/) for more details.
Regarding other news and features see [decompiler news page](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/news.shtml).

Update (12/3/2020):
The original answer was written ~2017, and since then IDA added MIPS decompiler support. AFAIK it was added in version 7.5.2.
See [here](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/compare/mips/) for comparison between decompilation and disassembly for various MIPS variants.